# Unable to deploying Rampart into Axis2

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, rampart

When am trying to deployin Rampart(rampart-1.6.2) into Axis2(axis2-1.6.0) am getting the below excpetion. I have followed the steps which are mentioned [here](http://techdiary.bitourea.com/2007/03/step-by-step-tutorial-to-use-rampart.html)

Exception trace:

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "AxisServlet" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "axis2.war".
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.load(Ljava/io/InputStream;)V
        at org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap.initializeXMLTooling(DefaultBootstrap.java:199)
        at org.apache.rahas.RampartSAMLBootstrap.bootstrap(RampartSAMLBootstrap.java:79)
        at org.apache.rahas.Rahas.init(Rahas.java:41)
        at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.initModules(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:252)
        at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.init(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:230)
        at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:93)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:584)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:454)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1981)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1955)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1874)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3154)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1518)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:671)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:44)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:184)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:361)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:51)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:180)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:96)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)

        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1520)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.load(Ljava/io/InputStream;)V
        at org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap.initializeXMLTooling(DefaultBootstrap.java:199)
        at org.apache.rahas.RampartSAMLBootstrap.bootstrap(RampartSAMLBootstrap.java:79)
        at org.apache.rahas.Rahas.init(Rahas.java:41)
        at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.initModules(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:252)
        at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.init(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:230)

    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy rampart in axis2 as explained in this blog  http://jayalalk.blogspot.com/2014/02/deploy-and-enable-rampart-in-axis2.html